# Using Preview with an old PDFkit

Tags: pdf, preview

With Mojave, I use to open multiple pdf at once with the old Preview9.0.app  (version of Sierra)

It doesn't work anymore with Catalina because of a conflict between Preview9.0.app and the new PDFkit framework.

Is there any way to embed the old PDFkit framework in Preview9.0.app ? Or redirect PDFkit calls to the old one ?

Comment: Is it a 32-bit app?

Comment: No, Preview 9.0 works normally except for pdf just because of PDFkit I guess.

Comment: Not without writing your own application. Why do you need Sierra's Preview in Mojave? Also, what exact errors are you getting in Catalina?

Comment: Preview9.0 crashes while opening any pdf. I need it because it can open very multiple pdf at once without separate tabs and search across very fastly.

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PVPDFView setEnablePageShadows:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feaa97a1e60'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Comment: You can still open multiple PDFs in the same window, if you want.

Comment: I can combine pdfs with Automator but there is no simple way to open them (at once without tabs) with Preview since High Sierra, except using Preview 9.0.

Comment: Preferences still has options to open all files in one window.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong. You can look at this capture https://i.imgur.com/6Y3xntm.png

Comment: Ah. My mistake. But there's almost certainly a better way of achieving the process/results you want, even if it's by using a different PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it was possible ! Cormiertyshawn895 dit it ! Thanks to him ! https://github.com/cormiertyshawn895/Retroactive/issues/1

Comment: Answers on AD should be more than just a link. Please add the steps required to solve the problem directly into your answer so it stands on its own.

Comment: Sorry but I am not a coder and I cannot explain how it works. The pull request is waiting for approval here https://github.com/frhd/macOS-Preview9.0/pull/3/files. 
Additional explanation are given here https://medium.com/@cormiertyshawn895/deep-dive-how-does-retroactive-work-95fe0e5ea49e

Answer (score -1):

Preview, like many other Apple-bundled apps, is designed to use the Operating System's frameworks. There is no practical way that the application can be reconfigured to use a separately supplied framework without having the source code and altering the application before compiling an altered version.

It's also worth mentioning that PDFKit in Sierra has many critical bugs!